# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Storemainteance_Helper_Data' Not Found

Tags: maintenance

I was trying to create a User Role for the first time and I've got the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Storemainteance_Helper_Data' not found in
>   /home/alex/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

Please let me know how I can solve this.

Thanks

Comment: do you have system.xml file for this module ? if yes show me the code of system.xml and config.xml

Comment: have you any custom extension with name Storemainteance

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. No I haven't done any custom extension with name Storemainteance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a call somewhere in your code to this:

```
Mage::helper('storemainteance')
```

When Magento tries to resolve class names through factory abstraction, if no grouped class name exists, it will automatically prepend the prefix `Mage_` in an attempt to resolve the class.  Basically, it cannot find a grouped class name 'storemainteance'.

Another thing to look at is the fact that the class name has a mis-spelling in it.

Mage_**Storemainteance**_Helper_Data

Find that helper reference and you will probably find your issue.

Comment: Ryan, it may be just half of the answer. Another reason for this may be using `translate="label" module="storemainteance"` somewhere in XML.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers. I can't find this "Storemainteance" label, which probably is the problem. Any help on how I can find this label will be appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: From your magento root, you can use: `grep -r "storemainteance" . > results.txt` in your command line.  You can also use an IDE or other search tool of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Magento may use your helper files for translation even if you dont use Mage::helper('storemainteance') in your code.

Try create

```
class {Package}_Storemainteance_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

and

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <test>
            <class>{Package}_Storemainteance_Helper</class>
        </test>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help me. However, I have no idea where to include the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I'm using Dexxtz/Storemaintenance and inside the file config.xml and replaced the misspelled word "mainteance" by "maintenance".

Thanks to all of you who tried to help.